# Running OpenCV in Terminal Only OS

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, yolov5, github-codespaces

I have been trying to run YOLOv5 (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) in Github codespaces. All the packages in the requirements.txt have been installed. I attached to `real.pt` model (https://github.com/Team4169/objectdetection/blob/main/yolov5/real.pt) I am using. It detects cones and cubes for FRC. It works on windows and linux (raspberry pi os w/ ui) but doesn't work on linux (codespace and raspberry pi os w/o ui). When I try to run the `python detect.py --weights real.pt --source 0` command the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/objectdetection/yolov5/detect.py", line 45, in <module>
    from models.common import DetectMultiBackend
  File "/workspaces/objectdetection/yolov5/models/common.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note running sudo doesn't fix this.

Comment: so install the `headless` variant of the package, and **no other variants**

Comment: It should be `python3 detect.py --weights real.pt --source 0`

Answer (score 0):

Writing some of my own Python that interfaces with RPi camera using Picamera2 and wanted to start using OpenCV. I installed the headless version to avoid installing X dependencies.

`pip install opencv-python-headless`

[OpenCV Python Headless documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/)

Not sure if you are running in to a similar issue. The YOLOv5 does have `opencv-python` in the `requirements.txt`. Maybe try replacing `opencv-python` with `opencv-pthon-headless`. But the application might be dependant on X or other UI libraries, and use those libraries.

The code I am writing, I want to avoid GUIs altogether to save resource usage.